# "the" before "history"

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

I have [learned](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ArticleForHistory/ggggp/post.htm) there is generally no article before history, unless we're talking about a specific one. But what about sentences where *history* doesn't mean neither *what has happened* nor *the story of humanity* but ***the past*** (since there is only one *past*)?

I feel like both

> This is the best way two people contacted in the history.

and

> This is the best way two people have contacted in history.

could be correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how it works. "The history" doesn't work by itself. History, as a whole, is too general for "the." (The same applies for "science.")

You can, however, use a specific history. "This has never happened before in the history of this nation" is a valid and common usage, and in fact requires the "the." It's a specific section of history.

Answer (score 0):

History is generally an uncountable noun. So you need to omit articles.

It becomes specific, and countable when talking about the history *of something or somewhere*.

> The history of Scotland is awesome.
>
> Those who learn from the errors of history are condemned to make new ones.
>
> History is bunk.

In your two examples you are talking about history generally. So you can't use "the".